# How to add data and print the data?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

Got two inputs namely name,dept from the user.

Have to call the method empreg in the program class and store the details using emplist object and print the data in screen.

How to do it?

**Employee.cs**

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace fundamentals
{
  public class Employee
  {
    private string name;
    private string dept;
    public string Name
    {
      get { return this.name; }
      set { this.name = value; }
    }

    public string Dept
    {
      get { return this.dept; }
      set { this.dept = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  

namespace fundament
{
  public class Program
  {
    public Employee[] empList = new Employee[2];

    string ename;
    string edept;

    Console.WriteLine("Name :");  
    ename = Console.ReadLine();  

    Console.WriteLine("Dept :");  
    edept = Console.ReadLine();  

    public object empreg(string name, string dept)
    {

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What class, course, tutorial or book do you use to learn C#? Related similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660840/how-to-add-value-to-a-list-in-which-it-is-a-value-type-in-a-dictionary and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655280/how-to-add-value-to-a-list-in-which-is-a-value-type-in-a-dictionary

Comment: [Reposting a closed or held question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302687/reposting-a-closed-or-held-question) • [Is it ok to to delete and repost a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176612/is-it-ok-to-to-delete-and-repost-a-duplicate-question) • [Dodging downvotes by deletion and repost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331598/dodging-downvotes-by-deletion-and-repost) • [A user is asking a question, deleting it and reposting it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321759/a-user-is-asking-a-question-deleting-it-and-reposting-it-again-and-again)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add value to a list in which is a value type in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655280/how-to-add-value-to-a-list-in-which-is-a-value-type-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: You cannot write statements directly inside a class. Is this doe inside the `main` method? Why does `empreg` have an `object` return type? If should either return an `Employee` or `void`. `public Employee empreg(string name, string dept) { var emp = new Employee { Name = name, Dept = dept }; empList.Add(emp); return emp; }`

Comment: this is a different question. I don't know to add the details using emplist and display the data here.

Comment: the question itself is like this.

Comment: @Oliver Rogier that doesn't answer my question